# how to create and update nodes and property using plain cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cypher-3.1, neo4j-desktop

How do I create and update nodes and property using plain cypher query?

Below is my query:

```
MERGE (c:contact {guid : '500010'})
ON CREATE SET
    c.data_source = '1',
    c.guid = '500010',
    c.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    c.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (s:speciality {specialtygroup_desc : 'cold'})
ON CREATE SET s.data_source = '1',
    s.specialtygroup_desc = 'fever',
    s.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET s.data_source = '1',
    s.specialtygroup_desc = 'comman cold',
    s.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (c)-[r:is_specialised_in]->(s)
ON CREATE SET
    r.duration = 1
ON MATCH SET
    r.duration = r.duration + 1
```

On the first run, node is created as "fever".
On the second run, I have updated the specialty_group to "common cold". But it is creating new node with "fever". I am not able to update the "fever" to "common cold".
What changes should I make to the above query?

Comment: I think you need to add a better description of what you're trying to do. Is your intent to create contact-specific instances of :specialty nodes, so one contact might have a cold specialty, which is a different node than another :specialty connected to a separate contact? Or do you want to have common specialty node shared across :contact nodes, and your intent is to change which node the contacts are pointing at?

Answer (score 0):

The `MERGE (s:speciality {specialtygroup_desc : 'cold'})` clause looks for a `specialtygroup_desc` value of "cold".

During the first execution, that `MERGE` clause finds no "cold" node -- so it creates one, and the subsequent `ON CREATE` clause changes it to "fever".

During the second execution, that `MERGE` again finds no "cold" node (since it is now a "fever" node), so it again creates a "cold" node and the `ON CREATE` clause yet again changes it to "fever". The `ON MATCH` clause is never used. This is why you end up with another "fever" node.

Unfortunately, you have not explained your use case in enough detail to offer a recommendation for how to fix your code.

Comment: Actually am doing incremental load . for the first time m loading the customer along with the specialty group "cold". Then i have changed the speccialty group of that customer to "fever". Now If i run the query specialty group of that customer should update to the "fever". M trying to update the specialty group of that custome. Create or update.

Comment: Can you update your question to show sample data, the sequence of invocations, and what you expect as the result of each invocation?

Comment: in the front end app for the for each customer there will be one many specialty group .On the first run contactid specialty
500010 cold

Comment: in the front end app for the for each customer there will be one many specialty group .On the first run contactid,specialty and the values is 500010,cold..On the second run i have updated specialty to "cold" to --> "fever" for that customer. I m trying to update the specialty node for that customer from "cold" to "Fever". In my case i have to update the "cold" specialty to "fever". result shuld be node(customer)-->updated specialty("fever").  In my above query trying to create and update the relatioonship node for that customer.

Comment: MERGE (c:contact {guid : '500010'})
ON CREATE SET
 c.data_source = '1',
 c.guid = '500010',
    c.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    c.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (s:speciality {specialtygroup_desc : 'cold'}) -----> need to updated "cold" to "fever" as specialty group
ON CREATE SET s.data_source = '1',
 s.specialtygroup_desc = 'fever',
 s.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET s.data_source = '1',
 s.specialtygroup_desc = 'fever',
 s.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (c)-[r:is_specialised_in]->(s)
ON CREATE SET
    r.duration = 1
ON MATCH SET
    r.duration = r.duration + 1

Comment: please let me know is there any other code fix for this

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to understand your comments.

Comment: I have loaded fs202 as a specialty node for the customer 500010 as shown in the picture. Now i have updated 'fs202' as new specialty 'cold02' . Please let me know is there any cypher query to update speacilty for that customer

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update all node "cold" to "common cold" and if not exists "cold" or "common cold", create new "fever" ?
My suggestion:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (ss:speciality {specialtygroup_desc : 'cold'}
SET ss.specialtygroup_desc='common cold', ss.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (c:contact {guid : '500010'})
ON CREATE SET
    c.data_source = '1',
    c.guid = '500010',
    c.created = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET
    c.lastUpdated = timestamp()
MERGE (s:speciality {specialtygroup_desc : 'common cold'})
ON CREATE SET s.data_source = '1',
    s.specialtygroup_desc = 'fever',
    s.created = timestamp()

MERGE (c)-[r:is_specialised_in]->(s)
ON CREATE SET
    r.duration = 1
ON MATCH SET
    r.duration = r.duration + 1
```